# How to import TSV files using DocArray?

Tags: python, csv, docarray

I have some data stored in a TSV. I saw that DocArray offers the method `from_csv()` to import it, but I can't find any good documentation about it. Is there a parameter to change the delimiter from comma to tab?

The only thing I found in the docs is this: [docarray.document.generators.from_csv](https://docarray.jina.ai/api/docarray.document.generators/#docarray.document.generators.from_csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs that you find mentions a parameter `dialect`:

> define a set of parameters specific to a particular CSV dialect. could be a string that represents predefined dialects in your system, or could be a csv.Dialect class that groups specific formatting parameters together. If you don’t know the dialect and the default one does not work for you, you can try set it to auto.

Actually, the value `auto` can successfully infer the tsv file type and delimeter, you just need to do:

```py
# run this command to download a sample file
# wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/alaeddine-13/76b4aa7805a347cf2cdf12db78e0a81c/raw/a7df1a867e8cf80b4c226f72f219d0b6f2cea8a2/sample.tsv
da = DocumentArray.from_csv('sample.tsv', dialect='auto')
```

In case you need a specific dialect, you can either provide a [Dialect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect) class or provide a dialect name available in [python's dialects list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.list_dialects).